# How to find total number of points in each polygon in an image

Tags: python, scikit-learn, polygon, opencv3.0, voronoi

I have a binary image as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuSmU.png). I want to find total number of points each polygon have.For a given image , each polygon has one point. I guess that the approach to solve this problem is to first find polygons in the image for that I used cv2.findContours but not able to get polygons. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal reproducible code sample. So others don't have to start at 0.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step I would try out [corner detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection#The_Harris_&_Stephens_/_Plessey_/_Shi%E2%80%93Tomasi_corner_detection_algorithms).

OpenCV demo of the Harris corner detecor is available [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d7d/tutorial_harris_detector.html).

```
# Detecting corners
dst = cv.cornerHarris(src_gray, blockSize, apertureSize, k)
```

The documentation of the function is to be found [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#gac1fc3598018010880e370e2f709b4345).